# Folding a Rose tree [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function foldRose which folds a general "Rose" tree. Here's the function for folding a normal binary search tree,

```
foldTree
:: (a -> b -> b -> b)   -- combining function
-> b                    -- base case
-> Tree a               -- input tree
-> b                    -- answer
foldTree c b (Bin x l r) = c x (foldTree c b l) (foldTree c b r)
foldTree c b Tip         = b
```

Here's all I got right now for foldRose,

```
foldRose
:: (a -> [b] -> b)   -- combining function
-> Rose a            -- tree
-> b                 -- answer
foldRose = undefined
```

What is really tripping me up is the definition. I've been trying to compare and apply the foldTree definition to foldRose but, I've had no luck figuring out exactly how to do that. Is someone able to help me get the ball rolling?

EDIT:
I think I'm making a progress but not quite there yet.

```
foldRose c (Node x xs) = c x (foldRose c xs)
```

Getting an error that xs is a list of Roses instead of one Rose. Which is true, but I don't know how to not have that problem.

Comment: Solved by mapping foldRose to the [Rose]

Comment: 1. You could reply to your own post with answer if you solved it. 2. Shouldn't you  take care of the empty case?

Comment: @Abastro the empty case here is `c []`